# Best way to aggregate logging data

Tags: mysql, aggregate

So I have a database that contains logs of people clicking a link. What I store is `id`, `country`, `referrer-domain`, `clickedat`. That last column is a timestamp.

At the moment there are not a lot of rows, but if this takes off it might be tens to hundreds of thousands of rows. What is the best way to query the database for things like this:

- Times viewed per day for the past month
- Top 20 countries that used your link
- Top 20 websites referring your link

Using a `COUNT(*)` would eventually be way too slow. I've seen techniques where you add another query to every update, insert, delete that happens to save in a special aggregation table. But I'm not sure that would work, as I'd like to have users be able to select two specific dates for example. Or I'd have to aggregate by day.

Comment: Maybe a NoSQL solution would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an indexed Date, column, so you're not doing date/time calculations on the fly, you should just be able to query it using normal aggregations.  It would take a long time before that would be 'way too slow' with properly formatted queries.

If it takes off, look into de-normalising the data as you describe, but don't optimise it prematurely!

Comment: That's actually a fine solution for the time being. It's slowly taking off, the service is being picked up by a bigger website that wants to offer it to their members, but it's just more total data, not more rows per users. They're all relative "small" users. Thanks!